# what is diffrent between windows and linux version?

Tags: linux, windows, flyway

We want to put the flyway folder on my application directory and release it, and our clients use both of the linux and windows server. We used sql-base migrations and Flyway command-line tool.
what is diffrent between windows and linux platform tools?
Can we use a linux platform tools for both? if no, what are same file or directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the Linux and Windows versions of Flyway is the type of Java Runtime Environment they include (e.g. `java` or `java.exe`), so you should make sure the contents of `flyway-<version>/jre` match the client's platform. Everything else should be the same.

Comment: And if you use containers for it, you don't even have to worry about the java runtime, windows, linux, AWS Developer Tools, Github Actions, Azure DevOps, all work exactly the same if you use a container. Makes all the coding around Flyway easier.